# Delete specific content in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data format shown below.

```
???m,"N0000001","????(M)","201405","201405","0.57674","0.60831"

???{???Y,"N0000003","????(M)","201402","201402","0.78170","0.68470"

?}???n?j?`??,"N0000004","????(M)","201407","201407","1.54956","1.54956"

???????Y,"N0000015","????(M)","201412","201412","0.95776","0.98891"
```

and I want to delete the 'N000000' these part. only leave the valid number. the output should like this

```
???m,"1","????(M)","201405","201405","0.57674","0.60831"

???{???Y,"3","????(M)","201402","201402","0.78170","0.68470"

?}???n?j?`??,"4","????(M)","201407","201407","1.54956","1.54956"

???????Y,"15","????(M)","201412","201412","0.95776","0.98891"
```

Does anyone know what kind of operation should I do?

Comment: is `regex` an option ?

Comment: If it's a fixed length `N000000` then Ctrl + H find and replace it... You can highlight the range to reduce potential impact elsewhere if it could occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange
    rngDB.Replace "N000000", ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

your data list is very unclear. Assuming the data commening with N000000 is in an individual cell, the formula you could use would be:

for data in cell A1, place formula in cell B1:

with ';' as a delimiter:

```
=right(A1;LEN(A1)-LEN("N000000"))
```

with , as delimiter

```
=right(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN("N000000"))
```